# Modify and return passed parameter

Tags: java, refactoring, software-design

I have code that has method like that modify and return the passed object parameter.

It strongly looks to me like a bad code smell.

```
public class Creator {
  public MyClass create(MyClass param) {

    SomeClass attr1 = createAttr1();
    SomeClass attr2 = createAttr2();
    //... more creation

    param.setAttr1(attr1);
    param.setAttr2(attr2);
    //... set other created attributes.

    return param;
  }
}


public class MyApp {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Creator creatorProcesss = new Creator();
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
    myClass = creatorProcesss.create(myClass);
  }
}
```

Is there a proper way to refactor it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change the return type of your method to `void` and the usage would become :

```
creatorProcesss.create(myClass);
```

Or better yet :

```
creatorProcesss.initialize(myClass);
```

since your method doesn't create a new instance, it initializes the passed instance.

You can also reverse the process - have an `initialize` method in `MyClass` which accepts a `Creator` argument and modified the current `MyClass` instance.

Then you `main` would become :

```
Creator creatorProcesss = new Creator();
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
myClass.initialize(creatorProcesss);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are passing a reference, you can just define the signature as void instead of returning the same reference. Alternatively, you can return a boolean flag based on success of operation inside your method.

```
public class Creator {
  public void create(MyClass param) {

    SomeClass attr1 = createAttr1();
    SomeClass attr2 = createAttr2();
    //... more creation

    param.setAttr1(attr1);
    param.setAttr2(attr2);
    //... set other created attributes.

    return;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree that it looks like a nasty code smell - in particular, you're introducing [side-effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)) by doing that.

Also, why does the object need to be created (in what appears to be a semi-initialized state) and then modified afterwards?  I would probably try to find a way to fully initialize the object before trying to use it - perhaps by using a factory, or the [Builder Pattern](https://dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-the-builder-pattern) (in the interest of full disclosure, this link points to one of my own articles).